# Recovering files from trusted installer/ windows.old

Tags: windows, windows-10

I had to do a repair install and I find a bunch of my files are now owned by trusted installer.
I'd like to try and get some of them back (saved games...) though googling for a solution I come upon two main responses.

1: Download this shifty software to access windows.old.

2: Do not under any circumstances change the settings for ownership of trusted installer files or you will die.

Which gives me two questions.

A: What are the negative effects of giving myself ownership of trusted installer files?

B: Is there a way to access these files without extra software?

Answer (score 1):

For those specific files, there should be no negative effects, assuming you can actually get the system to let you change their ownership (such files usually need to be manipulated through external means because even Administrator accounts can't mess with them).  The user itself exists for the purpose of ensuring that nobody messes with files that are being manipulated during updates, so outside of the specific case of the `windows.old` directory, it's generally a very bad idea to mess with them.  The only specific impacts with the `windows.old` directory are that it opens up another area for malware to potentially hide and that it may prevent rollback to the previous install (though given what you said, I doubt the last one is an issue).

As far as actually changing them, there are a couple of methods, but all of the officially sanctioned ones require booting into a recovery environment.  The method I normally use on my laptop when this happens is to boot into Linux, then copy the files elsewhere (this will clear out the ownership of the files).  A couple of my friends usually use Windows PE or recovery mode to access them and copy the data elsewhere, but that doesn't always work reliably from what I hear.

Comment: thanks. Curiously trusted installer also owns a few random image files on my old desktop. I'll try and launch from an ubuntu disk and see if I can get them.